# Convert NSNumber to int in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, nsnumber

I use `[NSNumber numberWithInt:42]` or `@(42)` to convert an int to NSNumber before adding it to an NSDictionary:

```
int intValue = 42;
NSNumber *numberValue = [NSNumber numberWithInt:intValue];
NSDictionary *dict = @{ @"integer" : numberValue };
```

When I retrieve the value from the NSDictionary, how can I transform it from NSNumber back to int?

```
NSNumber *number = dict[@"integer"];
int *intNumber = // ...?
```

It throws an exception saying casting is required when I do it this way:

```
int number = (int)dict[@"integer"];
```

Answer (score 208, accepted):

Have a look at the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSNumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html). Use the `intValue` method:

```
NSNumber *number = [dict objectForKey:@"integer"];
int intValue = [number intValue];
```

Comment: Implicit conversion is now disallowed with ARC.

Comment: basically `[key intValue]` (key is `NSNumber`)

Answer (score 62):

You should stick to the `NSInteger` data types when possible. So you'd create the number like that:

```
NSInteger myValue = 1;
NSNumber *number = [NSNumber numberWithInteger: myValue];
```

Decoding works with the `integerValue` method then:

```
NSInteger value = [number integerValue];
```

Comment: Why should he stick to the `NSInteger`?

Comment: `NSInteger` is a primitive type thats **much** faster during execution that `NSNumber` which is an object.

Comment: And what is `int`? A primitive too?

Comment: `int` is primitive too, yes. However it's maximum allowed number is less precisely defined. `NSInteger` is essentially just an alias to some primitive integer type that's known to be 32bit on 32bit machines and 64bit on 64bit devices.

Comment: So it's a good idea to use `NSInteger` over `int` in the most cases?

Comment: Yes, Apple suggests to.

Comment: Seelmann, but I guess that if I know the numbers I need are not large, it's ok to use `int` over `NSInteger`, right?

Comment: I'd recommend not guesstimating anything about native number arithmetics. You can sure use `int`, but there is little point in doing so, except for interfacing with cross-platform libs. And even then something like `uint32_t` would be better to use.

Comment: I'm sorry if I'm bothering you, I'm just trying to learn and understand more. I recently started learning Objective C working on a big project and I'm thinking about ways to refactor it. So, it's a good idea to replace `int` with `NSInteger` everywhere possible in the existing project, right?

Comment: Doing that would certainly make it more consistent with platform coding standards, yes.

Comment: Always use NSInteger.

Answer (score 4):

Use the NSNumber method `intValue`

Here is [Apple reference documentation](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSNumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSNumber/intValue)

Answer (score 1):

A less verbose approach:

```
int number = [dict[@"integer"] intValue];
```

Answer (score 1):

A tested one-liner:

```
int number = ((NSNumber*)[dict objectForKey:@"integer"]).intValue;
```