# Detecting if NSNumber is between 0 and 255

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, nsnumber

I am trying to detect whether a NSNumber is between 0 and 255 or not. Whenever I run the app, I receive the alert view that my number is greater than 255, even when it is not. I do not have this problem with 0.

```
if (redValue < 0) {

    NSLog(@"Red value is less than 0");

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Your number must be greater than 0." message:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];

    [alert show];
    [alert release];


} else if (redValue > 255) {

    NSLog(@"Red value is greater than 255");

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Your number must be less than 255." message:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];

    [alert show];
    [alert release];

}
```

Additionally, I receive this warning on the "else if (redValue > 255)" line: **Ordered comparison between pointed and integer ('NSNumber *' and 'int')**, So I'm assuming I have to convert this NSNumber to an integer?

Comment: See this question for more about converting from NSNumber to int : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3555906/how-to-convert-nsnumber-to-int-in-objective-c

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Should be:

```
if([redValue intValue] < 0) {
...

if([redValue intValue] > 255) {
...
```

Assuming it is an int. If it isn't go to the [NSNumber Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html) look under "Accessing Numeric Values" and replace `intValue` with the appropriate thing.

Answer (score 3):

use intValue to get the number as an int:

```
[redValue intValue]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (redValue.intValue >255)
{
    // it's greater than 255
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
[redValue intValue] > 255
```