# Error converting int into NSNumber

Tags: ios, int, nsnumber

I am fetching data from the web, and I am having problems with the numbers that are returned. For example, when the int 1 is returned from the server, and I try and convert that int to a NSNumber, the value of the NSNumber is 151241152. The number is slightly different every time, but it is always over 1 billion. Here is my code:

```
int agrees = (int)[info objectForKey:kWaveAgrees];
wave.numberOfAgrees = [NSNumber numberWithInt:agrees];
```

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to convert NSNumber to int in Objective-C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3555906/how-to-convert-nsnumber-to-int-in-objective-c)

Comment: Try an `NSLog(@"%@", [info objectForKey:kWaveAgrees]);`. What does that give you?

Comment: If the returned the value is of type `number` you can assign the integer value directly to `numberOfAgrees`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NSNumber is an object. You cannot cast it into an int, it must be unboxed first.

```
int agrees = [[info objectForKey:kWaveAgrees] intValue];
```