# How to correctly add input data to the tflite model in swift?

Tags: objective-c, swift, tensorflow-lite

Input shape of my tflite model - (18, 63) or 1134 numbers.

I get the data itself in objective-c code, and then I send it to swift code and an error already occurs there. In detail I do the following

1. Receive the data in NSMutableArray. The length of the array is 1134 NSNumber
2. Converting NSMutableArray to NSData

```
   NSData *d = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:_data];
   NSLog(@"output: %@", d);
   // output: {length = 18181, bytes = 0x62706c69 73743030 d4000100 02000300 ... 00000000 000034fd }
```

3. I send data to the swift code. 
   Swift code:

```
@objc public func predict(_ data: NSData) {
        guard
          let modelPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "model", ofType: "tflite")
        else {
            return
        }

        do {
          let interpreter = try Interpreter(modelPath: modelPath)
          try interpreter.allocateTensors()

          let inputData: Data = data as Data

          try interpreter.copy(inputData, toInputAt: 0) // <-- an error occurs in this line

          try interpreter.invoke()
          let outputTensor = try interpreter.output(at: 0)
        } catch {
          print(error)
        }
}
```

4. I get an error in the above line of code. Error: 
   `Provided data count 18181 must match the required count 4536.`

H

Comment: Why does the unarchived data have a length of 18,181, when you should have 4536?

Comment: I don't know why, it's just a bug that I don't know how to fix

Comment: I see you convert the ```NSMutableArray``` to ```NSData```. The length of the converted *data* is 18181 *bytes* (this represents the 1134 *numbers* stored in the array). Somewhere on the swift side you need to convert the data back to an array, you have to *unarchive* the data to get the array back *before* you pass it to the model.

Comment: The model accepts NSData / Data format data

Comment: Ok, I don't have tflite docs and don't use it, but then maybe you need to convert it to data differently e.g. use a property list encoding? The docs should give some working example of how to convert to the ```NSData``` it expects?

Comment: I used this tutorial https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/inference#load_and_run_a_model_in_swift . I haven't seen any other examples, as a rule, the cnn model is used everywhere and everything is done a little differently there. In my case, I just want to use a regular full-connected network

Comment: I checked that quickly - looks like that is using image data and you are using numbers. But do you have API docs somewhere.

Comment: I haven't come across an available tflite api for swift

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're converting to NSData wrong. The code doesn't show how you are constructing _data, but from the size logged it looks like this is the issue.
See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3555906/convert-nsnumber-to-int-in-objective-c) on how to extract value from the NSNumber object and do this before passing it to the swift function.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and that's what I used. I start with an array of type Double.

Then I convert it in float32:

```
guard let inputDataFloat32 = yourArray.compactMap({ d in
    Float32(d)
}) else { return }
```

And then in Data():

```
let inputData = inputDataFloat32.withUnsafeBytes { f in
    Data(f)
}
```

And you can get the output like so:

```
guard let data = outputTensor?.data else {
    return
}
    
var output = Array<Float32>(repeating: 0, count: data.count/MemoryLayout<Float32>.stride)
_ = output.withUnsafeMutableBytes { i in
    data.copyBytes(to: i)
}
print("Output: \(output)")
```